# Installing Ubuntu 9.10 on an encrypted disk

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu, encryption

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a laptop running Windows XP on an encrypted disk?  My company encrypts all laptops before distributing them.  When I try to install Ubuntu the installer reports that there is no OS on the system, since it cannot see the data on the HD.  I cannot of course choose the whole disk for installation nor partition it since it will possibly screw up my XP installation.  Is there any way around this?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I thought about using Wubi but I was afraid to screw up my bootloader since I am really new to the Linux world. I'll back up all my stuff first and try it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing Ubuntu from within Windows itself with [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer)?

[image: Wubi Installer Image]

There shouldn't be problems with reading the file system for partitioning this way since it's all done within Windows. This way, Ubuntu can also be uninstalled via Add/Remove programs if you don't like it.

Comment: John is also correct, try using wubi and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Best way around that is to buy a 4gb flash drive and install ubuntu on that, than just plug it in to the usb port on you laptop and boot from that. Or you could use vmware workstation and just download the iso of ubuntu and load it virtually